# How to delete files with ~?

Tags: command-line, files, wildcards

I have removed all my python code from the home directory, but when I do `ls` I get:

```
a11.py~ class1.pdf foobar.txt~ n1 pic.py~
```

When I do `ls` like this: `ls *.py` I get:

```
ls: cannot access *.py: No such file or directory
```

I still have lot of files like the above. Are they hidden files or what?

How do I solve this?

Comment: "tradition" says that those files are auto saved file from emacs or vim. as a suffix `~` has no special meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `~` is part of the filename:

```
ls *.py~
```

Thus, to delete all such files:

```
rm *~
```